# How to get a direct URL to a file on IBM Cloud Object Storage that has access key id and secret access key

Tags: api, url, ibm-cloud, cloud-object-storage

I am trying to access a file in a bucket on s3.us.cloud-object-storage and it has an access point id and secret access key and I cant find a way to type a url that gives me access.  Can some one help?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with the file when accessing it? Should it be accessible by everyone ("public") or just by you?

Comment: Its accessible by just the people that have the access key id and secret access which i do have.  I have pull the csv out of one of the buckets and perform some data manipulation in IntelliJ.  Any insight you give would be helpful.  Thank You

Comment: This seems like some form of misunderstanding COS. It is a storage service, not a cloud drive or storage box. You can create publicly available URLs, but you would need to code an app like https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/secure-file-storage to have your own "drop box" or "cloud drive".

Answer (score 0):

COS is s3 compatible so you can use the aws cli with the HMAC credentials, see https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-aws-cli

Alternatively can use the `ibmcloud cli` using your IBM IAM credentials after installing the cos plugin into the ibmcloud cli.  See https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage-cli-plugin?topic=cloud-object-storage-cli-plugin-ic-cos-cli

I just opened an ibm cloud shell to verify the instructions below.  On cloud.ibm.com see the shell in the upper left corner.

While the browser is open navigate to your COS instance, then the bucket.  On the left choose the `Configuration` for your bucket and copy the `Bucket instance CRN`  The CRN for the COS instance does not include the final :bucket:bucket-name but does include the ::

In the shell:

```
ibmcloud cos config crn --crn crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/713c783d9a507a53135fe6793c37cc74:bd19a0fa-74a0-4962-bfae-f1f4f8b9eea6::
ibmcloud cos buckets
ibmcloud cos objects --bucket tmp-s3fs-aafa2e74-89da-40d6-8a3a-bd33477901e9
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer...I am a super beginner andn its hardnto navigate this.  Do you know of a solution that follows the pattern of https://{endpoint}/{bucket}/{file}  but when I call this just by typing the url, it asks for credentials...where do I insert these credentials when typing the url..

Comment: It is required to use the API to write files to create buckets and write files.  If you make the bucket publicly accessible then you can read the bucket's content and objects in the bucket using the URL.